# Encrypted 18.04. install is not using the whole disk

Tags: 18.04, partitioning, encryption

I installed Ubuntu and chose encryption during the installation. The partition where dm_crypt-0 is sitting, is 398.5G big, and according to `lsblk` dm_crypt-0 is using the whole partition, but the logical ubuntu--vg volume is only using around 25% of it.

How can I make it use the whole available space? An lvresize only enlarged it to the current size. It was much smaller before.

Results of `lsblk` :

[image: lsblk output]

Comment: You didn't specify the Ubuntu 18.04 LTS product ISO you used (server, desktop etc); be it a *di*, `ubiquity` installer etc, as different 18.04 products are on different ISOs using different installers.  /boot/EFI cannot be encrypted as must comply with ESP standards; `/boot` encryption is dictated by installer/ISO used for installation (*and installation script*).  If you didn't use an ISO that uses full disk encryption, did you follow https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Full_Disk_Encryption_Howto_2019 ?

Comment: I used the official server install and checked the encryption checkbox. The problem could be solved by following https://packetpushers.net/ubuntu-extend-your-default-lvm-space/ but I had to extend dm_crypt-0 because it did not use the displayed size.

Comment: FYI:  Official server install?  Which one as I see 18.04 Server ISOs that use *di* and `subiquity`, with the installer selected by the ISO you download & use. If you use the *live* server then it's `subiquity` but you didn't state which *official* ISO you selected and used.  People tend to stop looking when they find something they want (18.04 Server) & may not notice there are multiple options (ie. (alternate ISOs exist for many releases, especially older releases like 18.04*)